# Get all the divs after a div and decrease by one their attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs that have an attribute: `rowNumber`.
one of them has an attribute: `isOpen=1`.

All the others that are after it have `isOpen=0`.

for example:

```
<div class="statusCell" isOpen="0" rowNumber="1">
```

I want to get all of the divs with class `statusCell` that are found after the div with isOpen=1, and decrease by one their rowNumber.

I need to do something like:

```
$('.statusCell[isOpen=1]').nextAll('.statusCell[isOpen=0]').each(function() {
    var rowNumber = $(this).attr("rowNumber");
    var newRowNumber = parseInt(rowNumber, 10) - 1;
    $(this).attr('rowNumber', newRowNumber.toString());
});
```

but it doesn't work because:

```
$('.statusCell[isOpen=1]').nextAll('.statusCell[isOpen=0]').length
```

is zero..

a sample code is:

```
<td class="DesignedTableTD">
    <div class="statusCell" style="cursor:pointer;" isOpen="0" rowNumber= "1">
       <p style="display:inline;" class="yellow" title="fd">
         <img alt="Active" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/play.png")" class="help"/>
       </p>&#9661;
    </div>
</td>
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: can you share the html sample.... it does look like those are not sibling elements

Comment: I'm not sure that you want to use `.nextAll()` but rather `.children()` is probably what you are after. As @ArunPJohny says, I think those not siblings, but actually children.

Comment: try this $('.statusCell[isOpen=0]').length as stated above the html code would be very helpful to answer your question.

Comment: need to see multiple instances of `statusCell` element to understand the relationship between them..

Comment: Neither rowNumber nor isOpen are valid attributes. You should look into data attributes instead.

Comment: From your update it is clear that they are not siblings so nextAll will not work

Comment: still your script can be simplified to `$('.statusCell[isOpen=1]').nextAll('.statusCell[isOpen=0]').attr('rowNumber', function(idx, rowNumber){
    return (parseInt(rowNumber, 10) || 0) -1;
})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextAll` selects next matching siblings of the selected element which is not the case here, you can use the `index()` method:

```
var $statusCell = $('.statusCell[isOpen]'),
          $open = $statusCell.filter('[isOpen=1]'),
              i = $statusCell.index($open);

$statusCell.filter(':gt('+i+')').foo();

// Decreasing attributes' value
// $statusCell.slice(++i).attr('rowNumber', function(_, value) {
//    return +value - 1;                           
// });
```

Note that `isOpen` and `rowNumber` are not valid attributes, if the Doctype of the page is HTML5 you can use `data-*` attributes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively...

```
var oStatCell = querySelectorAll(".statusCell[isOpen=1]");
for(i = 0; i < oStatCell.length; i++) {
    var cStatCell = oStatCell[i].querySelectorAll(".statusCell[isOpen=0]");
    for(j = 0; j < cStatCell.length; j++) {
        cStatCell[j].setAttribute("rowNumber", String(parseInt(cStatCell[j].getAttribute("rowNumber")) - 1));
    }
}
```

Not to say this is a better option, but I think it's nice to have a non-library-based option available.

querySelectorAll() documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll